# I have an SQL table. With an SQL request with PHP I want store the result of this request in a variable.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, variables

I have an SQL table. With an SQL request with PHP I want store the result of this request in a variable. The probleme is that this request have a lot of valors.

In other worlds I want to store in my variable a lot of IDs Maybe with an array but i dont now how. And i want to use variable for another SQL request using PHP.

What I want to do: With the IDs that I store in this variable, show all the names that have the same ID **BUT** this IDs of names are in another table. I want to use the IDs of the first table to second tables, and show all the names that correspond to the ID on mi web site. All the names (IDs) not just one.

I dont have the code yet.

I hope is an easy question, and you may help me thank you very much.

Comment: It's useful if you share table structures

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question in its current state is too broad and unclear. Consider to provide tables schema, sample data, desired output to illustrate your question. Especially because you don't have any code to show us.

Comment: ok im preparing my second question -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entrirly sure what you are asking here, but for the first part, storing everything in a variable is very simple, but if you write the script well, you dont have to use a new variable.

`$newVar = $_POST;`

BUT, you don't really need to do this, everything is already in POST, just access it with a key: `$_POST[name_of_what_you_want]`

I think what you are asking is the basics of the CRUD website / database method. Create, read, update, and delete.

You will get your info from the client in your script, ie GET or POST.

Validate and scrub this data, prepping it for insertion into the database.

Insert this data into your database. In your case you are talking about a relational database. Basically, you have a table which stores the bulk of the data, each of those entries, or rows as they are known, which has a unique ID. Then you have other tables that rely on that unique ID to link that particular row of data to something else, be it a page or a category, etc., of your website.

Now that the data is in the database, you can query it and pull out what you need, based on a set of criteria, that you make up as you need. Then you build your webpage and send it to the user.

Without providing specifics of your project, I am afraid I cannot help you much further, but I hope this helps.

EDIT - based on your comment.

Here is a pseudo mockup of what you are asking for.

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE id='id_number'";
$data = mysql_query($sql); <-- assuming you are using MySQL 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
   echo $row['name'];
}
```

What's going on? Query the database to pull out the rows with the ID you are looking for. Store them in an array, and step through that array, echoing the name to the user.

Comment: Ok, im sorry i didnt explain very well. 

I just want to show on my web site all the names that his ID correspond with the IDs of another table.

Comment: thank you so much let me try on my code @lampwins