# Add HTML ID or HTML Class in <?php the_category(); ?>

Tags: php, html

I would like to add a custom HTML class or HTML id to this:

```
<?php the_category(); ?>
```

According to WordPress:

```
 <?php the_category( $separator, $parents, $post_id ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category

I just need  a HTML id so what I did was

```
<?php the_category('custom-category'); ?>
```

but it's not working. Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555439/i-have-an-sql-table-with-an-sql-request-with-php-i-want-store-the-result-of-thi

Comment: This is HTML, not CSS. Please don't get the two mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo '<div class="custom-category">';
the_category();
echo '</div>';
```

Although. based on the page structure, you may be able to use an advanced CSS selector to select the same element. Refer to [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) for a complete list of CSS selectors.